# Sending data to a 1602 LCD in Mono C# over i2c

Tags: serial, i2c, screen, mono

How would I be able to put information on a 1602 lcd over SPI? I was thinking that it may be possible to write to the pin (like a file) with all the hex codes of the letters etc. or similar.

I'm a complete beginner at even trying to send something programatically through i2c.

Comment: SPI != I2C.  1602 doesn't support SPI or I2C natively, it has a parallel interface.

Answer (score 1):

The standard 1602 tpye character LCDs do not have an I2C interface as far as I know. Do you have an LCD display that has some active components added to work with I2C (I know people build PCB around them just for that)?

The LCDs without any added PCB circuitry I've seen use either a 4 or 8 bits mode (which you should probably get from the GPIO pins of the Pi) that need to be controlled in a specific way to get anything displayed...

Comment: I've seen some boards that are attached to the pins on the LCD, converting them to i2c. The board automatically translates the information and puts it on the screen. It saves quite a bit of wiring

Comment: @TheJamaicanGuy I have an I2C board, do I still need a library for this though? If so, have you found a C# one somewhere?